Prove the divergence of the sequence
I think my reasoning is flawed.
1. $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+2}}$. Prove that this sequence diverges.
Let's estimate the difference $x_{n+p} - x_n$:
$$x_{n+p} - x_n=\sum_{k = n+1}^{n+p} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(k+1)(k+2)}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+p+1)(n+p+2)}}*p$$
If we take $p = n$ here, we get:
$$x_{2n} - x_n\geq\frac{n}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Hence we see that this sequence satisfies the negation of the Cauchy criterion. Namely, at $\varepsilon=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$ for any natural $\mathbb{N}$, take $n=n_\varepsilon, m=2n_\varepsilon$ then it will have:
So, this sequence has no finite limit, i.e., it diverges.

One might also note that $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}}\ge\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac1n$ which is infinite as the harmonic series diverges.

This is fine up to $\ x_{2n} - x_n\geq\frac{n}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}}$
But then it is not clear how you get the next inequality, did you use $n\ge 1$  and said $2n+1\ge 3$ and $2n+2\ge 4$ ? Notice that is wrong direction for denominator.
Instead factor $n$ like this $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2+\frac 1n)(2+\frac 2n)}}$
Now you can use $2+\frac 1n<3$ and $2+\frac 2n<3$ and this is correct direction with $x_{2n}-x_n>\frac 1{\sqrt{9}}=\frac 13$

Thank you very much! But apart from that there are no other remarks ?

No, it's ok, once you've shown the difference between two limit terms is not going to zero, you are done, it's not Cauchy.
